# In algebra this notation is used a lot what does it mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, notation, vectors

If $p,q$ are vectors, what does 
$\langle p,q \rangle$ mean?

Comment: Maybe an [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space)?

Answer (score 2):

$\langle p, q \rangle$ usually refers to the inner product of $p, q$ where $p, q$ are members of some inner product space. For example, in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\langle x, y \rangle$ is often defined as $$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i$$

Comment: Who invented this notation? (possibly Dirac?)

Comment: I think Dirac took it further but didn't invent it, he used the Bra-ket notation for functions in a Hilbert space which looks similar

Comment: Ah thanks! My non mathsy friend said less than and more than haha this is a better answer

Comment: Just found in WP (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra–ket_notation#cite_ref-Grassmann_7-0) that actually Grassmann started with square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

It is one notation for the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).  Another is $p \cdot q$  In Euclidean space it is $\langle p,q\rangle = \sum_i p_iq_i$

Comment: I'm the \langle \rangle fairy, here to let you know that $\langle, \rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than <, > does :)

Comment: @PatrickStevens: I had used \lt and \gt, so I think I was OK for $\LaTeX$.  I think the angles are right for this.

Comment: The problem with \lt and \gt is that TeX treats them as binary relations, so the spacing becomes wrong.